# IE: jquery get not working (sometimes)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

near the end of `<head>` section (but not immediately before `</head>`) I have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "get", url: "http://somesite.com/getstuff",
                    success: function (data, text) {
                       ...
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {                        
                    }
                });

            });

    </script>
```

This works in firefox and chrome but only sometimes in IE 9 (10). Could anyone shed light on this?

Yes, indeed I forgot to say that by not working I mean that no http request is issued at all from IE (and no errors in console).

**Edit**

Well, I turned off the IE cache and everything works now. Hm, crap. I wonder how do I avoid this, I'll try to place script in the body and will report if this worked.

Comment: Can you please define what happens when it "does not work"? Is there an error? Does the server return an answer? Did you check the console?

Comment: if your parameters do not change IE is likely caching the result... try setting the cache property in the options to false

Comment: Is `somesite.com` your current domain? You may be falling foul of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it is my current domain

Comment: @ren Did you try emptying the cache and placing the script at the bottom of the <body> tag?

Comment: You can avoid caching in a couple of ways : i)Add a random parameter to your request. for example http://somesite.com/getstuff?param=Math.random() ii)Set the expires_on = Yesterday in the header of server response. iii) Setup jQuery to disable caching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE usually has caching issues.  Try setting ajax cache to false

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```